# How to store luasocket data using ffi?

Tags: sockets, lua, luajit

I would like to store a tcp client object returned by luasocket inside of a struct using ffi.
I tried to just store the variable in the struct like so:

```
ffi = require 'ffi'
socket = require("socket")

ffi.cdef[[
    
    typedef struct {
        void *Tcp;
    } ClientData;

    void* malloc(size_t);                   
    void free(void*);
]]


local Tcp = socket.bind("*", 12345)

local ptr = ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("void*"))

while true do

    local NewClient, Error = Tcp:accept()

    if NewClient ~= nil then

        local ClientData = ffi.cast("ClientData(&)", ptr)
        ClientData.Tcp = NewClient

        ClientData.Tcp:send("Hello World\n")
    end

end
```

But I would up with this error:

```
test2.lua:30: 'void *' has no member named 'send'
```

Can anyone help me?
The documentation said lua userdata can be stored in a void* in c.

Comment: `NewClient` has type "userdata", but after assignment `ClientData.Tcp` has type "cdata<void*>".  You have lost its correct type: userdata can have its specific methods, while `void*` can not.  You should store userdata in Lua variables, not in FFI cdata.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Egor.